# jrebel cause error in hybris when starting with debug mode

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, jrebel

I already set up some hybris projects and used jrebel in them, but this project is kind of different.

When I run my server with `./hybrisserver.sh debug` and `tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n`, it starts correctly and I can debug the server.

When I run my server with `./hybrisserver.sh debug` and `tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n -agentpath:%JREBEL_HOME%/lib/libjrebel64.dylib`, it doesn't start and I get the following error.

When I run my server with `./hybrisserver.sh` and `tomcat.javaoptions=-agentpath:%JREBEL_HOME%/lib/libjrebel64.dylib` (not the debug options!), it starts normally and jrebel is present in the log.

```
ERROR [localhost-startStop-4] [HybrisContextFactory] Error initializing global application context!
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultInterceptorRegistry' defined in class path resource [interceptor-spring.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'interceptorMappings'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'classAttributeAssignmentUniqueClassificationItemValidatorMapping' defined in class path resource [catalog-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'uniqueClassificationItemValidator' while setting bean property 'interceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uniqueClassificationItemValidator' defined in class path resource [catalog-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'categoryService' while setting bean property 'categoryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lerbsCategoryService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lerbsB2BUnitService' while setting bean property 'lerbsB2BUnitService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultLerbsB2BUnitService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'b2bCommerceUnitService' while setting bean property 'b2BCommerceUnitService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultLerbsB2BCommerceUnitService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'emailService' while setting bean property 'emailService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultLerbsEmailService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'b2bCommerceUserService' while setting bean property 'lerbsB2BCommerceUserService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultLerbsB2BCommerceUserService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'productService' while setting bean property 'productService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lerbsProductService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'priceService' while setting bean property 'priceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'erpPricingCatalogService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'netGrossStrategy' while setting bean property 'netGrossStrategy'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commerceNetGrossStrategy' defined in class path resource [commerceservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cartService' while setting bean property 'cartService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCartServiceForAccelerator' defined in class path resource [acceleratorservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'orderCalculation' while setting bean property 'orderCalculation'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultOrderCalculation' defined in class path resource [order-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'calculationService' while setting bean property 'calculationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'erpCartCalculationService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'erpPricingCartService' while setting bean property 'erpPricingCartService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'erpPricingCartService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'erpPricing' while setting bean property 'erpPricing'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'erpPricing' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'configurableErpPricingBackend' while setting bean property 'erpPricingBackend'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurableErpPricingBackend' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'legacyErpPricingBackendMongo' while setting bean property 'erpPricingBackendMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [legacy], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'legacyErpPricingBackendMongo' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'storeSessionFacade' while setting bean property 'storeSessionFacade'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultStoreSessionFacade' defined in class path resource [commercefacades-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'commerceCartService' while setting bean property 'commerceCartService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lerbsCommerceCartService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'commerceCartCalculationStrategy' while setting bean property 'commerceCartCalculationStrategy'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lerbsCommerceCartCalculationStrategy' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'promotionsService' while setting bean property 'promotionsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPromotionEngineService' defined in class path resource [promotionengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'commerceRuleEngineService' while setting bean property 'commerceRuleEngineService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCommerceRuleEngineService' defined in class path resource [droolsruleengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'platformRuleEngineService' while setting bean property 'platformRuleEngineService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPlatformRuleEngineService' defined in class path resource [ruleengine-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'kieSessionHelper' while setting bean property 'kieSessionHelper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultKieSessionHelper' defined in class path resource [ruleengine-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleEngineKieModuleSwapper' while setting bean property 'ruleEngineKieModuleSwapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultRuleEngineKieModuleSwapper' defined in class path resource [ruleengine-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleEngineCacheService' while setting bean property 'ruleEngineCacheService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCommerceRuleEngineCacheService' defined in class path resource [ruleengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleEngineCache' while setting bean property 'ruleEngineCache'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCommerceRuleEngineCache' defined in class path resource [ruleengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'commerceRuleEngineRaoCacheCreators' while setting bean property 'raoCacheCreators'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commerceRuleEngineRaoCacheCreators': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleGroupExecutionRRDProvider' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultRuleGroupExecutionRRDProvider' defined in class path resource [ruleengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleGroupExecutionRrdConverter' while setting bean property 'ruleGroupExecutionRrdConverter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultRuleGroupExecutionRrdConverter' defined in class path resource [ruleengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleGroupExecutionRrdPopulator' while setting bean property 'ruleGroupExecutionRrdPopulator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultRuleGroupExecutionRrdPopulator' defined in class path resource [ruleengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleGroupDao' while setting bean property 'ruleGroupDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultRuleGroupDao' defined in class path resource [ruleengineservices-spring-rule.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1362) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.jrLockAndRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:40002) ~[spring-context-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:41008) ~[spring-context-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.refreshContext(HybrisContextFactory.java:95) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$ApplicationContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFactory.java:263) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getApplicationInstance(HybrisContextHolder.java:87) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.createCoreApplicationContext(AbstractTenant.java:713) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.java:752) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartUp(AbstractTenant.java:685) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.assureTenantStarted(Registry.java:658) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateTenant(Registry.java:719) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.setCurrentTenant(Registry.java:566) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateMasterTenant(Registry.java:626) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.startup(Registry.java:444) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.core.ClassLoaderUtils.executeWithWebClassLoaderParentIfNeeded(ClassLoaderUtils.java:42) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.startRegistry(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:325) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.doInitWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:211) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:199) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:95) [coreserver.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699) [catalina.jar:8.5.51]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165) [catalina.jar:8.5.51]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:8.5.51]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412) [catalina.jar:8.5.51]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402) [catalina.jar:8.5.51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'classAttributeAssignmentUniqueClassificationItemValidatorMapping' defined in class path resource [catalog-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'uniqueClassificationItemValidator' while setting bean property 'interceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uniqueClassificationItemValidator' defined in class path resource [catalog-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'categoryService' while setting bean property 'categoryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lerbsCategoryService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lerbsB2BUnitService' while setting bean property 'lerbsB2BUnitService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultLerbsB2BUnitService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'b2bCommerceUnitService' while setting bean property 'b2BCommerceUnitService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultLerbsB2BCommerceUnitService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'emailService' while setting bean property 'emailService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultLerbsEmailService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'b2bCommerceUserService' while setting bean property 'lerbsB2BCommerceUserService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultLerbsB2BCommerceUserService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'productService' while setting bean property 'productService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lerbsProductService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'priceService' while setting bean property 'priceService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'erpPricingCatalogService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'netGrossStrategy' while setting bean property 'netGrossStrategy'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commerceNetGrossStrategy' defined in class path resource [commerceservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cartService' while setting bean property 'cartService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCartServiceForAccelerator' defined in class path resource [acceleratorservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'orderCalculation' while setting bean property 'orderCalculation'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultOrderCalculation' defined in class path resource [order-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'calculationService' while setting bean property 'calculationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'erpCartCalculationService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'erpPricingCartService' while setting bean property 'erpPricingCartService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'erpPricingCartService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'erpPricing' while setting bean property 'erpPricing'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'erpPricing' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'configurableErpPricingBackend' while setting bean property 'erpPricingBackend'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurableErpPricingBackend' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'legacyErpPricingBackendMongo' while setting bean property 'erpPricingBackendMap' with key [TypedStringValue: value [legacy], target type [null]]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'legacyErpPricingBackendMongo' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'storeSessionFacade' while setting bean property 'storeSessionFacade'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultStoreSessionFacade' defined in class path resource [commercefacades-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'commerceCartService' while setting bean property 'commerceCartService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lerbsCommerceCartService' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'commerceCartCalculationStrategy' while setting bean property 'commerceCartCalculationStrategy'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lerbsCommerceCartCalculationStrategy' defined in class path resource [lerbscore-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'promotionsService' while setting bean property 'promotionsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPromotionEngineService' defined in class path resource [promotionengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'commerceRuleEngineService' while setting bean property 'commerceRuleEngineService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCommerceRuleEngineService' defined in class path resource [droolsruleengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'platformRuleEngineService' while setting bean property 'platformRuleEngineService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPlatformRuleEngineService' defined in class path resource [ruleengine-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'kieSessionHelper' while setting bean property 'kieSessionHelper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultKieSessionHelper' defined in class path resource [ruleengine-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleEngineKieModuleSwapper' while setting bean property 'ruleEngineKieModuleSwapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultRuleEngineKieModuleSwapper' defined in class path resource [ruleengine-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleEngineCacheService' while setting bean property 'ruleEngineCacheService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCommerceRuleEngineCacheService' defined in class path resource [ruleengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleEngineCache' while setting bean property 'ruleEngineCache'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCommerceRuleEngineCache' defined in class path resource [ruleengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'commerceRuleEngineRaoCacheCreators' while setting bean property 'raoCacheCreators'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commerceRuleEngineRaoCacheCreators': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleGroupExecutionRRDProvider' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultRuleGroupExecutionRRDProvider' defined in class path resource [ruleengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleGroupExecutionRrdConverter' while setting bean property 'ruleGroupExecutionRrdConverter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultRuleGroupExecutionRrdConverter' defined in class path resource [ruleengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleGroupExecutionRrdPopulator' while setting bean property 'ruleGroupExecutionRrdPopulator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultRuleGroupExecutionRrdPopulator' defined in class path resource [ruleengineservices-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ruleGroupDao' while setting bean property 'ruleGroupDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultRuleGroupDao' defined in class path resource [ruleengineservices-spring-rule.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1534) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1281) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1314) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1280) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1178) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1347) ~[spring-beans-4.3.21.RELEASE.jar:4.3.21.RELEASE]
    ... 38 more
```

Now I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: Are configuring Jrebel for all projects or just your custom extensions?

Comment: @Zedex7 for the Wohle project, like it is described on the jrebel or hybris documentation

Comment: You are not going to customize code in OOTB extensions, all your custom code will be in custom extensions. So you can just enable jrebel for your custom extensions.

Comment: Do you have an example how to do that?

Comment: Its all dependent on rebel.xml file in your extension. If you are using IDE, configuring will be easy using Jrebel Plugin. Check "Project Configuration" section in official Jrebel documentation for your IDE. https://manuals.jrebel.com/jrebel/ide/index.html

Comment: to be honest, I never got running jrebel in Intellij with hybris. The jrebel hybris documentation shows just the way to set it up in the whole project

Answer (score 0):

below configuration to correct dev debug.

```
 tomcat.javaoptions=-agentpath:"C:/jrebel/lib/jrebel64.dll"
tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-agentpath:"C:/jrebel/lib/jrebel64.dll" -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Change the path accordingly.

Comment: I already tried to set the absolute path, had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

to work with JRebel rebel.xml is necessary, create this file:rebel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://www.zeroturnaround.com/alderaan/rebel-2_0.xsd">
 
    <classpath>
        <dirset dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom/test">
            <include name="**/classes"/>
            <!--Uncomment next line in case of exception '..java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hybris.cockpitng.util.DefaultWidgetController...'
                when trying to access backoffice-->
            <!--<exclude name="**backoffice**"/>-->
        </dirset>
    </classpath>

 
</application>
```

Modify hybris
to start JRebel with hybris, one of the ways is to modify tomcat wrapper.conf
go to hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/conf
create wrapper-jrebel.conf: make copy of wrapper.conf and rename it to wrapper-jrebel.conf

insert there three lines

wrapper-jrebel.conf::::::::::::

```
wrapper.java.additional.20=-Drebel.base=C:\Users\test\.jrebel
wrapper.java.additional.21=-javaagent:C:\Users\test\.IdeaIC2018.1\config\plugins\jr-ide-idea\lib\jrebel6\jrebel.jar
wrapper.java.additional.22=-agentpath:C:\Users\test\.IdeaIC2018.1\config\plugins\jr-ide-idea\lib\jrebel6\lib\jrebel64.dll
```

create wrapper-jrebel-debug.conf: make copy of wrapper-debug.conf and rename it to wrapper-jrebel-debug.conf
insert there three lines

wrapper-jrebel-debug.conf

```
wrapper.java.additional.23=-Drebel.base=C:\Users\test\.jrebel
wrapper.java.additional.24=-javaagent:C:\Users\test\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\config\plugins\jr-ide-idea\lib\jrebel\jrebel.jar
wrapper.java.additional.25=-agentpath:C:\Users\test\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\config\plugins\jr-ide-idea\lib\jrebel6\lib\jrebel64.dll
```

modify hybrisserver.bat

to load JRebel separately insert there two blocks

hybrisserver.bat

```
IF  "%MODE%"=="jrebel" (
    SET _YWRAPPER_CONF=%~dp0tomcat/conf/wrapper-jrebel.conf
    SET MODE=run
)
IF "%1"=="jrebel_debug" (
    SET _YWRAPPER_CONF=%~dp0tomcat/conf/wrapper-jrebel-debug.conf
    SET MODE=run
)
```

to load JRebel as usual in debug mode insert there one block

hybrisserver.bat

```
IF "%1"=="debug" (
    SET _YWRAPPER_CONF=%~dp0tomcat/conf/wrapper-jrebel-debug.conf
    SET MODE=run
)
```

now run

jrebel

```
hybrisserver.bat jrebel
```

or

jrebel debug

```
hybrisserver.bat jrebel_debug
```

or if you choose usual debug mode